# Как получить значения всех select в php массив?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Есть страничка с select и кнока add.
Например мне нужен три продукта и я нажав кнопку получил три select поля.
Как получить значения всех select в массив php при нажатии кнопки добавить?
Спасибо)

```js
var selectionCounter = 0
    function cloneSelect() {
        var select = document.getElementById("statement")
        var clone = select.cloneNode(true)
        var name = select.getAttribute("name") + selectionCounter++
        clone.id = name
        clone.setAttribute("name", name)
        document.getElementById("selectContainer").appendChild(clone)
       

    }
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-md-8 inputGroupContainer">
  <div id="selectContainer" >
    <select class="form-control" id="statement" name="statement">
     <option value="1">One</option>
     <option value="2">Two</option>
     <option value="3">Three</option>
     <option value="4">Four</option>
     </select>
   </div>     
   <button onclick="cloneSelect()">Добавить продукт</button>
</div>
<div style="text-align: right">
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-group btn-success" value="Добавить" >
<a href="suppliers.php" class="btn btn-group btn-danger">Отмена</a>
                    </div>
```

Comment: у `select`-ов должно быть `name` по типу `name="product[0]"`, `name="product[1]"`

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц как потом узнать количество этих массивов?

Comment: [count](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.count.php). А название будет `product`